# When is TInterfacedObject.Destroy called (a ScopedLock class)

Tags: delphi, interface, synchronization, locking

i'm wondering when an instance of a TInterfacedObject derived class is destroyed and who calls the destructor. I wrote a ScopedLock class, which should automatically call the Release
method of a synchronization object when the instance goes out of scope. It's an RAII concept known from C++, but i don't know if it is guaranteed that the destructor is called, when the lock instance goes out of scope.

```
ILock = interface
end;

ScopedLock<T: TSynchroObject> = class(TInterfacedObject, ILock)
strict private
    sync_ : T;
public
    constructor Create(synchro : T); reintroduce;
    destructor Destroy;override;
end;

implementation
{ ScopedLock<T> }

constructor ScopedLock<T>.Create(synchro: T);
begin
    inherited Create;;
    sync_ := synchro;
    sync_.Acquire;
end;

destructor ScopedLock<T>.Destroy;
begin
    sync_.Release;
    inherited;
end;

{ Example }
function Example.Foo: Integer;
var
  lock : ILock;
begin
  lock := ScopedLock<TCriticalSection>.Create(mySync);
  // ...
end;  // mySync released ?
```

It works fine in a simple test case, but is it safe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that is save. Your code

```
function Example.Foo: Integer;
var
  lock : ILock;
begin
  lock := ScopedLock<TCriticalSection>.Create(mySync);
  // ...
end;
```

is compiled as the following pseudocode

```
function Example.Foo: Integer;
var
  lock : ILock;
begin
  lock := ScopedLock<TCriticalSection>.Create(mySync);
  lock._AddRef;  // ref count = 1
  try
// .. 
  finally
    lock._Release;  // ref count = 0, free lock object
  end;
```

You can see that when **lock var** goes out of scope its ref count is decremented, became zero and lock object is automatically destroyed.

Answer (score 6):

The only problem is if the function is inlined: the local variable containing the ILock reference will be promoted to the scope of the function calling the inlined function. That may cause the lock to live longer than you wanted.

On the other hand, there's no need to actually declare a variable to hold the interface reference, if you write a function (e.g. a class function called Create) that returns an interface reference (as opposed to an object reference). The compiler will create a hidden local to receive the return value (as all managed types like interfaces and strings are actually returned by passing a result variable). This hidden local will act just like the explicit local.

I wrote more about it here: http://blog.barrkel.com/2010/01/one-liner-raii-in-delphi.html

Comment: Good article.. Can you tell me how the delphi compiler decides to inline a function or not? Are there any methods to prevent/enforce inlining?

Comment: @hansmaad: Unless you have {$INLINE AUTO} active, it will never automatically inline a function not marked with the inline directive. But $INLINE AUTO doesn't use a very smart heuristic - it will inline every function below a certain size, and can easily lead to a size explosion. This means that it's unlikely that $INLINE AUTO will be in effect. Thus, you need only worry about it if you yourself mark the function for inlining with the 'inline' directive at the end of the procedure header.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that the approach you espouse, whilst correct, is actually better than good old Try/Finally.  You have taken a solution that is clear and explicit and replaced it with one that is obscure and opaque.

Real work Delphi code is full of Try/Finally and so it should be a natural idiom.  I can't see the downside of writing:

```
mySync.Acquire;
Try
  //do stuff
Finally
  mySync.Release;
End;
```

Comment: Because it's less code?  Or, because it makes the scope explicitly obvious at the point where it's created.  There are probably other reasons too.  Try/finally is not bad, but other techniques can be good too you know :)

Comment: @David M given that you have to be used to reading and parsing Try/Finally anyway then you may as well use it wherever it does the job. Having multiple ways to protect a resource (leaking or serialisation) just, to my mind anyway, creates extra complications when reading and checking code. I guess I'm from the Python school of "one way to do things" as opposed to the Perl school of "many ways"!!

Comment: @Daivd H: For me the "one way to do things" is to use RAII techniques when ever possible. I can't go wrong with it. Whenever i acquire a serialization i'm sure i'll get the release at the right place, without writing additional lines of code i will forget sooner or later.

Comment: @hansmaad If all your codebase uses the RAII idiom then this seems a reasonable approach to me - it's when you have a mix of RAII and Try/Finally that I would find objectionable. One downside of RAII in Delphi is that you can't scope more locally than the procedure level as you can in C++, for example.  For me another factor against RAII is that it hits the heap and since my app is highly multi-threaded and performance is all for me, avoiding the heap is critical.